# CentOS 7 disk usage analyzer always says home full?

Tags: centos, disk-usage

The Disk Usage Analyzer tool on CentOS 7 always says that usage is at 100% for the `/home` dir. Even if I delete significantly large files from the offending directory, the usage remains reported at 100% (while the size shows GBs less of storage actually used). Eg. I first see...
[image]
and

```bsh
[airflow@airflowetl ~]$ df -h /home
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos_mapr001-home  140G   66G   75G  47% /home
```

Then after reducing the space in that directory, I see...
[image]
and

```bsh
[airflow@airflowetl ~]$ df -h /home
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos_mapr001-home  140G   50G   91G  36% /home
```

So

1. before even doing anything, it tells me there is more space available (75G), yet the disk analyzer reports full and
2. after removing files, it still shows that usage is 100% despite reduced actual disk usage. I would just ignore this and take the info from the `df` command, were it not for the fact that there does appear to be storage problems (eg. complaints of not enough disk space when using things like PyCharm IDE, etc.).

Anyone know what is going on here? How can this be fix?

Comment: You are misunderstanding what that's showing you. It's saying that 100% of the USED space in `/home/` is under the `/home` and subsequently `/home/airflow` directories.

Comment: @jordanm I suspected I was misinterpreting something. Yet the reason I even looked at all was because I was shown a storage alert popup (saying I only had 2.5GB of space left) when the disk usage was at 70GB in the `/home/airflow` dir and was redirected to the disk analyzer by the popup. Yet the disk analyzer seems to say that there is about 350GB available. Could you help explain thiat?

Comment: Note the word "total". You have 350GB available total across all of your filesystems, not all on /home.